# Usar stylesheet en un qtablewidget para mandar propiedades de una cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy tratando de cambiar el color del texto y fondo de un ítem en un qtablewidget con este código:

```
tabla.item(0,0).setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item {border: 1px solid red;}")
```

Donde tabla hace referencia a un QTableWidget.

Sin embargo, no hace nada ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar el comando que señalas deberia lanzarte un error ya que el QTableWidgetItem no tiene el metodo setStyleSheet().

Por otro lado los Qt Style Sheets no se pueden aplicar a items especificos señalando coordenadas, puedes aplicarlo a ciertos items que tienes ciertos estados como por ejemplo *pressed*, *selected*, etc.

Por lo anterior descartamos el uso de qss, QTableWidgetItem tiene metodos para señalar los colores del texto y de fondo usando los métodos [`setForeground()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setForeground) y [`setBackground()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setBackground), respectivamente.

Ejemplo:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10)

    it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("hola mundo")
    it.setForeground(QtGui.QColor("red"))
    it.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("orange"))
    table.setItem(0, 0, it)

    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]